# How to direct TypeScript/WebPack to output all, individual d.ts files to single flat directory?

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, bundler, type-definition

I'm using WebPack and TypeScript to create a component library. Everything is working and building as expected, except TypeScript (ts-loader or tic) outputs the .d.ts files in the same folder hierarchy as the source. While I could just write a cleanup script to move them into a flat build folder with their .js counterparts, I would prefer if they were output there to start with.

`declarationDir` only changes the relative base path, but doesn't give any kind of structure to how I want the files to be laid out. Is there a way in TypeScript, ts.config, and/or WebPack to output them all to the same flat folder as the .js files? I plan to implement dts bundle for the bundled library file, but I still want individual dts files for the individual component outputs (similar to the `material-components-web` project).

Comment: There is webpack plugin for that ([source is inline in this medium article](https://medium.com/@vladimirtolstikov/how-to-merge-d-ts-typings-with-dts-bundle-and-webpack-e8903d699576)). See also  https://github.com/SitePen/dts-generator and  https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4433

Comment: Thanks, I've seen some examples on how to bundle them, but I also need the individual .d.ts files for each output js as well, as far as I know. For example, I have a myLibBundle.min.js that is a UMD bundle of all my files that would have its own .d.ts, then individual components like myDropDown.min.js should also have its own .d.ts file for ES6 modules. Is that correct, or would one bundled .d.ts serve both needs?